# SQL: Get maximum value in query where column is an array

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get the maximum id value from the following table using SQL where name is 3 is contained in the array of that column:

```
id name
1   [2,3]
2   [3,5,6]
3   [7,8]
```

This is what I'm trying (with a lot of combinations):

```
SELECT `MAX(id)`
FROM `table`
WHERE `name`
IN ( 3 )
```

I should get the result `2` since `3` is contained in id 1 and 2.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support arrays, so I really don't know what you are talking about.  It sounds like you need to learn about junction tables and joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use LIKE and not IN since IN is like comparing a whole string with exact match. LIKE is comparing a string to a part of a string (each % means that anything can replace it)

```
SELECT `MAX(id)`
FROM `table`
WHERE `name` LIKE '%3%'
```

Also, I'm not sure about mysql syntax but I think it should be

```
MAX(`ID`) and not `MAX(ID)`
```

Comment: No problem:) I'll appreciate accept to my answer if it worked for u @NunoNogueira